# Center text in angular snackbar

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-material2

what would be the correct way to center text in an angular snackbar?

I've tried this, which doesn't work:

```
let config = new MatSnackBarConfig();
config.panelClass = 'center';
this.snackBar.open(message, undefined, config);
```

and then in some css file (either the same component, or in the global file):

```
.center {
   justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Use the built in `horizontalPosition` property in the config https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api#MatSnackBarConfig

Comment: @user184994 that refers to the position of the snackbar itself, not the alignment of the text inside the snackbar, unless I'm mistaken

Comment: According to material guide, it seems that left-align is the correct way for text: https://material.io/design/components/snackbars.html

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with `open()` and `panelClass` but you need to modify your CSS:

```
.center > .mat-simple-snackbar {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Material Guide aside, this works for our software product:

```
.mat-snack-bar-container {
    text-align: center;
}

.mat-simple-snackbar {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `panelClass` parameter worked for me.  StackBiltz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/center-text-on-snack-bar).

Use `text-align: center` instead.

Comment: Yes it works, thanks, but that's with 'openFromComponent'. Can you make it work with 'open' as in my original question ?

Comment: While your example does use `open` and not `openFromComponent` your question is titled 'Center text in angular snackbar' and nowhere do you specify you cannot use `openFromComponent`.  My StackBlitz was based off the example from the docs.  That said, I tested using the `open` function with the `panelClass` parameter and Angular Material does not respect the alignment even though the class is applied to the element.  Could be a bug in Material :(.  If you need to center the snack bar text I suggest using `openFromComponent` as we've seen that it works as expected.

Comment: Re-reading this I sound pretty defensive and for that I apologize.  I'm sorry it doesn't seem to work using `open`!

Answer (score 0):

```
const config = new MatSnackBarConfig();

config.panelClass = ['message-position'];

let snackBarRef = this._matSnackBar.openFromComponent(SnackbarMessageComponent, config);


 ::ng-deep .message-position {
        position: fixed;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate3d(-50%,0,0) !important;
    }
```